# Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. i Input `..1` is `order == 0`. x comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r, inext

really hoping someone might be able to help me!

I am trying to subsample raw fossil occurrences csv, using iNEXT package and SQS subsampling.

**I am getting this error:**
Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. i Input `..1` is `order == 0`. x comparison (1) is possible  only for atomic and list types

**From this piece of code:**

```
for(i in 1:length(quorum_levels)) {
estD <- estimateD(stage_freq, datatype = "incidence_freq", base = "coverage", level = quorum_levels[i])
estD <- filter(estD, order == 0)       #filter for species richness values
estD$quorum_level <- quorum_levels[i]
estD$reference_t <- totals$n            #add sample sizes in extra column
estD$midpoints <- midpoints
estD_list[[i]] <- estD
```

**I have tried using 'dplyr::filter()', as other forums suggest but still get the same error**

Thank you

Comment: If "order" is not a column name in `estD`, `filter` will attempt to compare the function `order() == 0`, which is invalid.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.